# How to add scrollbars to a GLUT application?

Tags: opengl, glut

I just want to know that how to make a scrollbar using GLUT library?

Is there any function to make a scrollbar in glut library?

I'm just a novice user, and I've created a window (top-level) using glut library. Now I want to add a scrollbar on this window.

Can anyone tell me how to put scrollbar on glut window (top-level)?

Comment: Go back to previous questions you asked and accept the answer that solved your problem

Comment: to accept an answer you must click on the tick sign on the left side below the vote up/down arrows

Answer (score 2):

Glut is quite a low-level library and doesn't pretend to be a fully fledged GUI toolkit.

1. You could create objects yourself with GLUT to draw an arrow down, an arrow up and the lift bar.. but that could be a lot of work.
2. Or you can use a proper GUI library like [GLUI](http://glui.sourceforge.net/), or other.